# Detect state (over, up, down) of button in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I searched the document but didn't find the way to detect the changing state of button. Anyone know the way? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by detecting this?

Comment: I'd like to change the color of button based on the state of button.

Comment: Well then, why can't you do that in the Flash IDE itself where you are creating the button?. Just provide different background colors for the different states of the button.

Comment: I have to use action script to do this.

Comment: Read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279157/how-do-i-set-the-state-of-a-simplebutton-with-actionscript-3

Comment: I think your link does not refer my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, are you creating your button through code? (SimpleButton)?

Comment: Provide more information (what button? fl.controls.button? what have you tried? what is your goal?) to your question, there's no point in tickling every little detail out of you in the comments, is there?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, I use spark.components.Button. I want to change the different colors of the button when the state button is changed (up, down, ..). For example: state up: yellow; state down: red

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you're using Flash Professional and that you're in fact trying to detect mouse events on a MovieClip?

The code below will detect of a button is hovered over and then trigger a function:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, buttonEventListener);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, buttonEventListener);

function buttonEventListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (e.type) {
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER:
            //on mouse over
        break;

        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT:
            //on mouse out
        break;
    }
}
```

The lack of information means this is just a guess so apologies if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but it's not my question. Sorry for my unclear question.